# Overcome "Duplicate Status Message" in fb api php

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Facebook wont allow to post duplicate message. But once I successfully post the message and for the second time I tried posting same thing; can I check or know programatically that its duplicate?

My code

```
$res = $facebook->post('/'.$fbuser['id'].'/feed',  $post,$access_token);
```

It returns error for duplicate message and code below it won't run.

How to check the error and skip it to run code below easily even if error occurs?

Comment: Catch the exception ... But why does this happen in the first place, why does your app not know what was posted already?

Comment: My app knows what was post earlier that's why its generating fatal error with Duplicate status messaage and preventing code below to run.

Comment: That’s not what I meant. I meant, why are you letting this error occur in the first place? If your app knows it has already posted message X - then why is it even _trying_ to post message X again?

Comment: i even try catch the code

Comment: Please don’t post extended code snippets in comments, that is hardly readable. Edit your question, and show the code in there.